# How can we insert update delete operation on wegrid in mvc4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I want to implement Insert, Update, delete operation on WebGrid in MVC4. How I can do that?

This is my Web Grid Code

```
@model IEnumerable<MVC24Jan.UserTable>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ShowRecord";
    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model);
}

<h2>ShowRecord</h2>

<div>
@grid.GetHtml(
    tableStyle: "webgrid",
    headerStyle: "head",
    alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
    columns:grid.Columns(
            grid.Column("UserId"),
            grid.Column("UserName"),
            grid.Column("Address")
            )

        )
</div>
```

And this my controller code

```
public ActionResult ShowRecord()
    {
       DBLayer db = new DBLayer();
       var usertablList= db.GetAllRecord();
       return View(usertablList);
    }

 public List<UserTable> GetAllRecord()
    {
        List<UserTable> userTable = new List<UserTable>();
        userTable = entity.UserTables.ToList();
        return userTable;
    }
```

How can I implement Insert, Update and delete operation on this grid?

Comment: I got some reference form http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/695850/Complete-CRUD-Operations-in-MVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you read the article: http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/E2S9150113-Enhancing-WebGrid-with-Insert-Update-and-Delete-Operations.html 
A few months ago it was help me with similar problem